# How to access an array of dictionaries?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, dictionary

I want to use an array of dictionaries to store all the content of an Excel workbook to later process it and make operations in memory.

I have defined that the first row of the Excel workbook is the key and the rest of rows are content. As I have one key for many values, I need to store them in a different container (this would be the array).

A sample of the content

```
Code Name Surname
1    a     b
2    c     d
```

The code:

```
For Each rcell In ws.UsedRange.Cells
   If rcell.Row > 1 Then
        ReDim Preserve aRows(rcell.Row - 2)
        'Set aRows(rcell.Row - 2) = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
        Set pInfo = New Scripting.Dictionary
        pInfo.Add Key:=Cells(1, rcell.Column).Value, Item:=rcell.Value
        'aRows(rcell.Row - 2).Add Key:=Cells(1, rcell.Column).Value, Item:=rcell.Value
        Set aRows(rcell.Row - 2) = pInfo
    End If
Next rcell
```

This code creates an array of dictionaries.

When I try to access the data I get an error.

I know that at least it is storing values because when I use:

```
debug.print(ubound(aRows))
```

I am getting the value (1) in this case.

I tried accessing the content with

```
for each row in aRows
    debug.print(row.key)
next row
```

However, this is not accepted. How do I access the data?

An alternative or something more simple would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this?

```
Dim d, k
For Each d in aRows
    For Each k in d.keys 
        Debug.Print k, d(k),
    Next
    Debug.Print vbCrLf
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

you could use

```
Dim myRow as Variant, key as variant
For Each myRow In aRows
    With myRow 
        For Each key In .Keys
            Debug.Print key, .Item(key)
        Next
    End With
Next
```